# How to specify 2 variables in a for loop in bash shell?

Tags: bash, for

I have multiple image files in a folder and have created a folder for each file. Now I want to `cp` one file in each folder.

I used

```
for i in `seq 1 9`; do mkdir $i; done
```

and then to copy all the files into the folders. I tried to use

```
for s in Whats* && i in `seq 1 9`;do cp $s $i;done
```

```
for s in *; do for i in `seq 1 9`;do mkdir $i;done;cp $s $i;done
```

Which obviously did not work.
(the names of all the files start with WhatsApp)

How can I copy one file at a time in each folder?

Comment: You want to create one directory for each file? Then why do you create exactly nine directories? Do you have nine image files?

Comment: Welcome, you say "multiple" files and "created a folder for each file", but your loop only creates 9 directories not apparently related to the files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you want directories with integer names, and that you want to have one directory per file that matches the `./WhatsApp*` pattern:

```
shopt -s nullglob

counter=0
for name in ./WhatsApp*; do
    counter=$(( counter + 1 ))
    mkdir "$counter" && cp "$name" "$counter"
done
```

This tries to create a directory for each matching name, and if that succeeds, it copies the file to that new directory.  The `mkdir` call would fail if that directory already exists, or if you don't have write and execute permissions in the current directory.

I set the `nullglob` shell option before the loop to avoid running a single iteration of the loop if there are no names matching the given pattern.  Without setting `nullglob`, the loop would run once with `$name` set to the literal string `./WhatsApp*`.